# Using tpolecat's recommended scalac flags with Play in Scala

Tags: playframework, lint, scalac

Play generates scala classes from routes files, twirl templates. When I add scalac linting flags, sbt picks up generated classes making it impossible to use together with play.

I really want to use https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat all these nice linting rules to increase code quality, but I am unsure how to exclude the generated files for scalac flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the compiler warning of *"Unused import"* on Play Framework/Twirl templates' `@(...` when using the `sbt-tpolecat` plugin.

I solved it by combing the *sbt-tpolecat* plugin with *Silencer*, https://github.com/ghik/silencer.

I added *sbt-tpolecat* to `/project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("io.github.davidgregory084" % "sbt-tpolecat" % "0.1.9")
```

I added *Silencer* to `build.sbt`

```
val silencerVersion = "1.4.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  compilerPlugin("com.github.ghik" % "silencer-plugin" % silencerVersion cross CrossVersion.full),
  "com.github.ghik" % "silencer-lib" % silencerVersion % Provided cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

And then importantly I filtered out the `views` package in `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions += "-P:silencer:pathFilters=views"
```